# Could somebody tell me how to analyze the bytearray keys from redis?

Tags: redis, arrays, jedis

I got a key like this:
"\x04y\x03\x00\x00K"
from my redis, and I totally confused about its meaning.

Are "\x04" represents for a hex string and "y" stands for a ascii char? Is so, why does the key combine both?

Thx in advance.

edit:
I am using Jedis(a java client for redis) and make key as byte arrays.
My codes(in java) are some like this:

```
jedis.set(aByteArr, value)
```

While running the code, I opened the native client provided by redis, executing "MONITOR" command to see what key is actually being saved in redis. And this is what I have found:

... SET "\x04y\x03\x00\x00K" "aString"

Comment: Redis never mange data nor key, both of this is probably due to your Redis client or how are you passing data to it. For anyone to be able to help you, can you show as some actual code example which show this issue?

Comment: Thank you for replying! I have updated my question, hopefully it can be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

\x represents a hex char escape. So the byte array key is encoded in a hex characters sequence in redis.

Comment: there are no hex characters there only, there are some other charachters aswell, in this example key ends with "\x00K"... here is another example of key value:  "\x03\xcc\x1b\xe0\xe0yT" <-- how to convert this either into String or byte array ?